# How do ascii art 3d engines work?

Tags: graphics

I've seen some pretty cool demos involving 3d ascii art videos. Does anyone what algorithms are used for doing this?

Comment: Pretty much the same as everyone else `:)`

Comment: Do you mean like the youtube feature that was going around a while back?

Comment: @Dimitar: Maybe something like that

Comment: Was any of the answers given (;) ) useful to you?

Comment: @phresnel: I gave you an upvote

Comment: @Casebash: But it doesn't answer your question?

Comment: The answer here may be helpful: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/87883/how-do-i-render-my-3d-game-in-ascii-art

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same as with ordinary, monochrome pixel graphics. You or some algorithm classifies the perceived brightness of some ascii-characters, put them in some lookup table, and then draw very blocky graphics.